# AzurePowershell Task Cannot Find Profile.ps1

Tags: azure, powershell

In Azure Devops, I have a YAML pipeline that executes a Powershell task that:

- Appears to invoke my script, but no output is echoed to the logs, and
- The task ends with an error, `Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1'.`

How do I:

- get PS to echo the results to the pipeline logs, and
- resolve the error at the end of the task

---

The step:

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@4
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: SetAzureFirewallRule'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '***'
    ScriptPath: SetAzureFirewallRule.ps1
    ScriptArguments: '-ServerName {myserver} -ResourceGroup {myrg} -AzureFirewallName {rulename}'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

The script file is straight forward:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'None')]
param
(
  [String] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $ServerName,
  [String] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $ResourceGroup,
  [String] $AzureFirewallName = "AzureWebAppFirewall"
)
Enable-AzureRmAlias -Scope CurrentUser
$agentIP = (New-Object net.webclient).downloadstring("http://checkip.dyndns.com") -replace "[^\d\.]"
echo "IP is $($agentIP)"
New-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -ServerName $ServerName -FirewallRuleName $AzureFirewallName -StartIPAddress $agentIp -EndIPAddress $agentIp
```

> Note I had to deviate from the [script recommended by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) by adding `Enable-AzureRmAlias -Scope CurrentUser`. This script works as expected when execute from my development machine, including echoing of the output.

When it executes, the following is logged:

```
##[section]Starting: Azure PowerShell script: SetAzureFirewallRule
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
Version      : 4.159.3
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [Learn more about this task](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613749)
==============================================================================
##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\az_2.6.0\Az.Accounts\1.6.2\Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
##[command]Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud
##[command] Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId *** -TenantId ***
##[command]& 'd:\a\1\s\SetAzureFirewallRule.ps1' -ServerName *** -ResourceGroup *** -AzureFirewallName ***
##[command]Disconnect-AzAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
##[error]Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1'.
##[section]Finishing: Azure PowerShell script: SetAzureFirewallRule
```

I have tried this with different hosts:

- windows-latest
- windows-2019
- vs2017-win2016

with the same results.

Comment: Instead of using `echo`, change it to `Write-host "IP is $($agentIP)"`. I've never tried using echo within Azure DevOps release flows so don't know if that is causing your logging issues, but I always use `Write-host`. I might also add more logging so that when it does output to the logs, you can see at what point it's failing.

Comment: @Nick No, don't use `Write-Host`.  `echo` is just an alias for `Write-Output` which is `stdout`.

Comment: @OP: Use `-NoProfile` if you can when calling the powershell script.  Something is trying to load the user `$Profile`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 post it as an answer, it's correct :)

Answer (score 1):

In executing the script, it looks like there's a failure loading the user profile.

You can work around this in two ways:

- create a dummy profile

  ```
  New-Item -Path $Profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost -Force
  ```
- don't load profiles

  ```
  powershell.exe -NoProfile -File ...
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` here might fix your path issue.

```
ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/SetAzureFirewallRule.ps1'
```